# Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm running an embedded Cordova Web view in an existing Xcode project. The app runs, but fails to load any plugins: A `Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml`. The JS interfaces are present, but they can't connect to the native implementations.

I've tried adding plugins with `plugman`, and with `cordova plugin add`. I'm not sure what the difference is, they just seem to copy the plugin files to different directories. In either case, I have to manually add the source files to my project, but the errors persist. I don't understand why the error is talking about `config.xml` when he official Cordova CLI-generated Xcode project has an unmodified config.xml, without any  tags - how is that project able to find its plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong config.xml file... Cordova makes a copy of the source config file in the project root, and stores it in the `platforms/ios/<Project name>` directory when you run `cordova prepare`. This version has a  tag for every plugin added.

I copied this file to my existing Xcode project, and it loaded the plugins successfully.